# LSTM how batch size and sequence length affect memory

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a question regarding batch size and sequence length. Let’s suppose that I have 10 different independent time series, each of length 100.

5 are of a person doing one activity, and the other 5 are of a person doing another activity.

I want to create an LSTM that will be able to remember the sequences all the way from the first sample in each sequence and classify test samples that I input into one activity or the other.

Now, for a first try, let’s say that I can input test-samples of length 100. How would I do this? Would I create an LSTM and then feed in data of the shape [10, 100, 1] in one go? Or would I feed in data of the shape [1, 100, 1] 10 times? The question here is that does batching affect how the LSTM will memorize past inputs? I do not want the LSTM to remember between independent sequences, but I do want it to remember all the way from the beginning of each time sequence.

Secondly, let’s say that I want to now chunk up the sequences I use to train the LSTM. The goal remains the same as before. So now I window the sequences into chunks of 10. Do I feed it in as [10,10,1] for each sequence? If I do this, will the LSTM memorize the temporal dynamics of the sequence all the way to the beginning? Will doing the LSTM this way be analogous to not chunking up the sequences and feeding them in full length?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the part of your question that has to do with batching. There are two reasons to batch.

1. It is more efficient for the computer to do the matrix multiplications in batches. If you are doing it on a CPU then part of the efficiency comes from being able to cache the matrix and not have to reload it from memory. During evaluation, the sequences in the batch do not interfere with each other. It is the same as if each one is computed individually.
2. During training, having multiple sequences in a batch reduces noise in the gradient. The weight update is computed by averaging the gradients of all the sequences in the batch. Having more sequences gives a more reliable estimate of which direction to move the parameters in order to improve the loss function.

Comment: Using a larger batch size is actually [not performing better](https://twitter.com/ylecun/status/989610208497360896?lang=en)! That is a big misconception in the field. The reason for large mini batche is mostly that you only have to update once after the batch, and not for every sample, which saves you some computational time. Also, the whole point of SGD is to use the "noise" in samples to allow for a greater range of possible solutions. Also, the main computational advantage for batches is only visible when processing on GPUs, where you do have to copy after each weight update.